# The Guid Is not passed Correctly in MVC4?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi the GUID is not passed  correctly.

**My Tables**

**Customer**

CustomerID uniqueidentifier primarykey not null,

DisplayName varchar(100)

PrintName varchar(100)

**CustomerAddress Table**

CustomerAddressID uniqueidentifier primarykey not null,

CustomerID uniqueidentifier null,

AddressID  uniqueidentifier null

**Address**

AddressID uniqueidentifier primarykey not null,

DisplayName varchar(100)

Street varchar(100)

Location varchar(100)

AreaID Uniqueidentifier null,

Pincode varchar(100)

**My Model**

```
public class CustomerModel1
    {
        public System.Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string PrintName { get; set; }
}

public partial class CustomerAddressModel
    {
        public System.Guid CustomerAddressID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> CustomerID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> AddressID { get; set; }

   }

 public partial class AddressModel
    {
        public System.Guid AddressID { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> AreaID { get; set; }
        public string PinCode { get; set; }
   }
```

**My ViewModel**

```
   public class CustomerViewModel
   {
    public System.Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public System.Guid CustomerAddressID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid AddressID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> AreaID { get; set; }
    public string PinCode { get; set; }
 }

public class VisitorsEntities1 : DbContext
{

public DbSet   Customer { get; set; }
public DbSet CustomerAddress { get; set; }
public DbSet Address { get; set; }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
  public ActionResult Create()
    {
        VisitorsEntities1 db = new VisitorsEntities1();                    

 ViewBag.AreaID = new SelectList(db.Area, "AreaID", "DisplayName",   "PrintName");

   return View();
    }



    [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Create(CustomerViewModel viewmodel)
    {

 ViewBag.AreaID = new SelectList(db.Area, "AreaID", "DisplayName",   viewmodel.AreaID);
       var Cusobj = Guid.NewGuid();
       var CusAddobj = Guid.NewGuid();
       var Addobj = Guid.NewGuid();


      var Customerobj = new Customer()
        {
            CustomerID = Cusobj,
        DisplayName = viewmodel.CustomerName,
        PrintName = viewmodel .CustomerName
   };


  var CustomerAddressobj = new CustomerAddress()
        {
            CustomerAddressID = CusAddobj,
            CustomerID = viewmodel.CustomerID,
            AddressID = viewmodel.AddressID
         };


      var Addressobj = new Address()
        {
            AddressID = Addobj,
            DisplayName= viewmodel.CustomerName,
            Street=viewmodel.Street,
            Location= viewmodel.Location,
            AreaID = viewmodel.AreaID,
            PinCode= viewmodel.PinCode
  };
     db.Customer.Add(Customerobj);
        db .CustomerAddress.Add(CustomerAddressobj );
        db.Address.Add(Addressobj);


   db.SaveChanges();


   return View()
 }
```

Here the AreaID is SubForm So I used ViewBag to bring dropdown in the View and Pass the Guid. Now my issue is with Customer Address Table.

```
 var CustomerAddressobj = new CustomerAddress()
        {
            CustomerAddressID = CusAddobj,
            CustomerID = viewmodel.CustomerID,
            AddressID = viewmodel.AddressID
         };

Here CustomerAddressID is new Guid is working fine. But

   CustomerID = viewmodel.CustomerID,
   AddressID = viewmodel.AddressID
```

The Guid is not passed correctly for this two lines . In table these column is 00000-0000-0000-0000 It didnt show any error and also its not passing the GUID correctly. I donno what the issue is. Please any one help to resolve these problem?

Error

[My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyKd7.png)

Thanks.

Comment: what are you getting in `viewmodel.CustomerID` and `viewmodel.AddressID` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using specual attributes to automatically generate Guid key on insert.

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public System.Guid CustomerID  { get; set; }
```

Here `Key` says it is primary key, `DatabaseGenerated` instructs to make key field auto-generated

**EDIT**

Note, that auto-generated identity fields are assigned to new entity only after save:

```
using (var db = new Context())
{
    var customer = new Customer();

    // Here customer.CustomerID is empty     

    db.Customers.Add(customer);
    db.SaveChanges();

    // Here customer.CustomerID is assigned
}
```

Comment: ok and i use this                                                                                         var CustomerAddressobj = new CustomerAddress()
        {
            CustomerAddressID = CusAddobj,
            CustomerID = viewmodel.CustomerID,
            AddressID = viewmodel.AddressID
         };